# hardcode or a file for text in java

Tags: java, string, text

I'm learning programming and started to think how people usually add text to their programs. I mean if I have a program which has say thousands of sentences. Do i write them all in class files like this

```
String str="hello world";
```

Or do I put it in a separete file and call that file from my code somehow?

Comment: Consider having a look at [Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/).  While this is a means for generating multi-language applications, it's also a good idea if you're only developing for a single language, as it's easier to change text in one or two resource files, then trying to dig it out of your source code

Comment: You may also consider using [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)

Comment: @Arvin 's answer semms to be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in an external properties file, that way when you have to change the values you don't have to recompile your whole project, just updating the properties file will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is called internationalization (i18n) and there are techniques and libraries for making it easier. But you're *learning* programming. Figure out that part later. Maybe just make messages `static final Strings` or inline String literals for now.

Comment: For God's sake, he said "thousands of sentences"

Comment: That sounds like an enterprise Spring CRUD app. It took me a long time to go from learning to program to needing a message file for that kind of scale. The closest I got was a quiz game with ~100 hardcoded questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the property file (Message.properties).with java API java.util .

Answer (score 0):

Hi my suggestion is you can use file structure and use in your java application
For eg:File file=new File("nameOfFile.txt");